# JAX-WS RI: Best way to implement a Method Interceptor

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, aop

I want to provide my own method interceptor for my webservice invocations. Basically, this method interceptor should be called *right before* the real method is called... See the snippet below:

```
public class MyMethodInterceptor {
  public Object invoke(Object t, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    // do some magic, such as tracing, authorise, etc...
    return m.invoke(t, args);
  }     
}

// ....    

public class MyWebServiceImpl implements MyWebServiceInterface {
  public String greet(final String name) {
    return "Hi there, " + name;
  }
}
```

The idea is that everytime that the webservice gets invoked, it will be dispatched through my interceptor. I've looked at hooking up my own `InstanceResolver`, but it is getting out of control. I know how to do this in CXF and with JAX-RS (Jersey) + Guice.

JAX-WS provides `handler-chains`, but these handlers get invoked *way too early* (i.e., much before the method invocation), so I do not have the needed information at this point.

What is the best way to do this with the Referene Implementation of JAX-WS?

Answer (score 0):

In a jax-ws handler you are just before the real thing, you have access to the content of entire SOAP message, what you need that isn't available yet?

EDIT:

Some examples, to use in the handler:

```
public String getMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
    ByteArrayOutputStream soapEnvelope = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    message.writeTo(soapEnvelope);
    soapEnvelope.close();
    return new String(soapEnvelope.toByteArray());
}

public String getMethod(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
    return body.getFirstChild().getLocalName();
}
```

Comment: I need to know which method and with which parameters will be invoked. The problem is that there are custom annotations on the methods of my interfaces, so I need to access the java.lang.reflect.Method somehow.

Comment: Accessing the SOAP message you can get the name of the method and the parameters. About the reflection, having the name of the method, can't you do what you need?

Comment: I need to extract annotations from the method parameters, and also to get the Java-type (not SOAP-Payload) arguments... Could you please show me a snippet/api/javadoc? Regards

Comment: I used the handlers for accounting, I just save the method name, getting it from the SOAP message converted to a string. Edited my answer to show how I did it.